# PureRenderMixin in an ES6 React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Is there any way to include a mixin in a React ES6 class component? (i.e `extends React.Component`)? If so, what is the official way of doing it?

I'd like to include `PureRenderMixin` in one of my components that has an immutable state to speed up the diffing process.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are typically two solutions to mixins in ES6-style React classes:

1. Create a higher-order component (e.g. [here](https://gist.github.com/acdlite/453f227f5e5cbbf105f8))
2. Use a decorator if you're willing to enable early-stage ES7 proposals in Babel (e.g. [here](https://github.com/felixgirault/pure-render-decorator))

I haven't actually tried the library I linked for #2, but decorators strike me as an elegant replacement to mixins.

Comment: I appreciate you doing this research for me :)

Answer (score 13):

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/shallow-compare.html

> [shallowCompare](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/shallow-compare.html) is a helper function to achieve the same
>   functionality as PureRenderMixin while using ES6 classes with React.

```
import shallowCompare from 'react-addons-shallow-compare';

export default class SampleComponent extends React.Component {

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    // pure render
    return shallowCompare(this, nextProps, nextState);
  }

  render() {
    return <div className={this.props.className}>foo</div>;
  }
}
```

[Source code](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v15.0.0/src/addons/ReactComponentWithPureRenderMixin.js#L41-L43) of [`PureRenderMixin`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/pure-render-mixin.html) is:

```
var ReactComponentWithPureRenderMixin = {
  shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) {
    return shallowCompare(this, nextProps, nextState);
  },
};
```

So, when You use [`PureRenderMixin`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/pure-render-mixin.html), You actually use [`shallowCompare`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/shallow-compare.html)

UPDATE [15.3.0](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1530-july-29-2016):

> Add `React.PureComponent` - a new base class to extend, replacing [`react-addons-pure-render-mixin`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/pure-render-mixin.html) now that mixins don't work with ES2015 classes.

Comment: What exactly is the diff since you __can__ use `PureRenderMixin` with `es6`?

Comment: @Tjorriemorrie, If You talk about code like `this.shouldComponentUpdate = PureRenderMixin.shouldComponentUpdate.bind(this);` in constructor, than it just another way to use `shallowCompare` addone.
See https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v15.0.0/src/addons/ReactComponentWithPureRenderMixin.js#L41-L43

Answer (score 0):

Not yet, according to the documentation.

Source: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#no-mixins

Answer (score 0):

I use [react-mixin](https://github.com/brigand/react-mixin) if i want to have mixins in my es6 react components, but I didn't try this library with `PureRenderMixin`.